# Ternary operator in Javascript and grouped sentences

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have the following ternary operator condition. Is there a way of the second if statement to be included somehow in line 1, so I don't need to make another if statement? The first condition, if true, should prepare the display status change and also the checkbox change.

```
function change_properties(display){
    var display_r = ( display === 1) ? 'block' : 'none';

    /*THIS LINE - can it be integrated in the ternary if-else condition above? */
    if(display) jQuery("#checkbox").prop('checked',false);

    jQuery("#field").css("display", display_r); 
}
```

Comment: Have you run out of disk space?

Comment: Just curious, normally I prefer completely explicit sentences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please** write it like this, assuming it is ok to have display truthy rather than ===1

```
function change_properties(display){
   $("#checkbox").prop('checked',!display);
   $("#field").toggle(display);
}
```

or if you ONLY want to uncheck when display is 1 (truthy):

```
function change_properties(display){
   if (display) $("#checkbox").prop('checked',false);
   $("#field").toggle(display);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is functionally equivalent. The OPs code only changes the `checked` prop when `display` is true; your code changes it every time.

Comment: Checked and it is not exactly identical. It does not work as desired. Thanks anyway, it was a very clever attempt.

Comment: Fixed it. Likely no need for a ternary

Comment: Now it goes perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, if you're willing to write *really hard to read code* then yes, it's technically possible:

```
var display_r = ( display === 1) ? jQuery("#checkbox").prop('checked',false), 'block' : 'none';
```

You could use `&&` instead of the `,` operator...  exploiting the fact that the string `'block'` is truthy.

For that matter, why have the next line of code in its own line?

```
jQuery("#field").css("display", ( display === 1) ? jQuery("#checkbox").prop('checked',false), 'block' : 'none');
```

In short, lines of code are not the enemy...

**EDIT:** Fixed the order around the `,`, which I don't know off the top of my head since I literally never do this.

But okay. Let's just write something sensible, without using the ternary operator for fun:

```
var display_r;
if (display === 1) {
    display_r = 'block';
    jQuery("#checkbox").prop('checked',false);
}
else {
    display_r = 'none';
}
jQuery("field").css("display", display_r);
```

Comment: i.e., please don't ever do this

Comment: The "," syntaxys throws an error and the Javascript doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

IMO better if you could write clear and easy to read code like following :

```
function change_properties(display){
    if(display){
         jQuery("#field").css("display","block");
         jQuery("#checkbox").prop('checked',false);
    }else
         jQuery("#field").css("display","none");

}
```

Or you could use `show()/hide()` :

```
function change_properties(display){
    if(display){
         jQuery("#field").show();
         jQuery("#checkbox").prop('checked',false);
    }else
         jQuery("#field").hide();

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of the second if statement to be included somehow in line 1, so I don't need to make another if statement?

It's possible, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

```
function change_properties(display){
    jQuery("#field").css("display", display === 1 && jQuery("#checkbox").prop('checked',false)
                                  ? 'block'
                                  : 'none'); 
}
```

To be clear, I really think you ought to go for the second function from [mplungjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35561060/1989425):

> ```
> function change_properties(display){
>    if (display) $("#checkbox").prop('checked',false);
>    $("#field").toggle(display);
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes, it seems the best solution. It was just curiosity, I don't really like using ternary operator, but was not seeing how it could be made to perform several instructions at once. The "," separator syntaxis of some answers do not work.

Comment: @Cesar It doesn't surprise me that the comma operator doesn't work; I don't recall commas being used for that in JS.

Comment: Yes, I looked for the syntaxys in several languages and didn't find a proper way of grouping several instructions, this is why I asked here. When I tried the comma suggestions, they threw error. At the end, I am using explicit instructions in independent lines, which is clearer, as confirmed by vast majority of contributors.

Comment: Seems I was wrong. [JS does have the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)...